# jQuery show DIV on Dropdown - Show First DIV before selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not a strong coder, but I cobbled together the following HTML/Jquery from a few posts here. It can all be found on [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2evuej72/2/)  My dropdown and selections are working for the most part, but I would like State 1 and State 2 to just be labels and not change the current selected option.  I would like on page load for my first option "All Locations" to be displayed, then disappear when other options are selected.  Pretty straightforward, but all options I have seen did not show first option shown on page load.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<select name="options" id="options">
<option value="page-section-20"> All Locations</option>
<option value="">State 1</option>
<option value="page-section-24"> - City 1</option>
<option value="page-section-28"> - City 2</option>
<option value="page-section-32"> - City 3</option>
<option value="page-section-36"> - City 4</option>
<option value="">State 2</option>
<option value="page-section-40"> - City 1</option>
</select>
```

and here is my jquery

```
$('#options').on('change', function () {
if(this.value === "page-section-20"){
    $("#page-section-20").show();
} else {
    $("#page-section-20").hide();
}
    if(this.value === "page-section-24"){
   $("#page-section-24").show();
} else {
   $("#page-section-24").hide();
}
        if(this.value === "page-section-28"){
   $("#page-section-28").show();
} else {
   $("#page-section-28").hide();
}
            if(this.value === "page-section-32"){
  $("#page-section-32").show();
} else {
   $("#page-section-32").hide();
}
                if(this.value === "page-section-36"){
   $("#page-section-36").show();
} else {
    $("#page-section-36").hide();
}
                    if(this.value === "page-section-40"){
   $("#page-section-40").show();
} else {
   $("#page-section-40").hide();
}
});
```

Comment: You should make this a code snippet here instead pointing to jsFiddle

Comment: Thanks!  I will do that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `optgroup` to display the state as a non-selectable label.  You can also forego checking which item is selected and just hide them all by default and then showing the one that is selected. Additionally, to show the default value by default, simply trigger (manually call) the event's function with `.trigger('change')`:

```js
jQuery('#options').on('change', function() {
  var section_ids = [20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40]
  section_ids.forEach(id => jQuery('#page-section-' + id).hide())
  jQuery('#' + this.value).show();
}).trigger('change')
```

```css
#options {
  color: #35beed;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-color: #35beed;
  border-width: 2px;
}

#locations div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Schedules</h1>

<div id="locations">

  <select name="options" id="options">
    <option value="page-section-20"> All Locations</option>
    <optgroup label="State 1">
      <option value="page-section-24"> - City 1</option>
      <option value="page-section-28"> - City 2</option>
      <option value="page-section-32"> - City 3</option>
      <option value="page-section-36"> - City 4</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="State 2">
      <option value="page-section-40"> - City 1</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <div id="page-section-20">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
  </div>

  <div id="page-section-24">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
  </div>

  <div id="page-section-28">
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
    <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
  </div>
  <div id="page-section-32">
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
    <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
  </div>
  <div id="page-section-36">
    <h2>Section 5</h2>
    <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
  </div>
  <div id="page-section-40">
    <h2>Section 6</h2>
    <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Awesome on the Opt Group!  Thanks that helped a ton.  I re-read my post again and it was not super clear.

Comment: I am looking to have the All Locations stay in the option menu.  But the I would like the DIV Page-Section-20 to display on page load then have the option menu work as normal once a selection is made by the user.

Comment: @Zedwinski Did you try the snippet above?  Isn't Section 1 (page-section-20) selected and showing by default?  Then when you select a city, doesn't it change?

Comment: Ahh!  Yes it is!  I just assumed I messed up my ask.  BTW - Voltron was the best cartoon of the early-mid 80's.

Comment: Defender of the Universe

Comment: This also worked on my site so this will make the above described worked. Thanks!

Comment: Terrific, but this is using ES6 make sure your site doesn't need to support IE11 and older.  You'll have to research what an arrow function is and convert it back to anonymous function syntax, if so.  It won't be much work (just a few more characters)

Answer (score 1):

First to remove the default option when some other option is selected, you could add this piece of code to your `onChange` event:

```
$(this).find('option').eq(0).remove();
```

Then to group options you should use `optgroup` tag.

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2evuej72/3/)

Comment: This worked great however I think I asked the wrong question.  See comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `disabled` for option you don't like to select

```
<select name="options" id="options">
<option value="page-section-20"> All Locations</option>
<option value="" disabled>State 1</option>
<option value="page-section-24"> - City 1</option>
<option value="page-section-28"> - City 2</option>
<option value="page-section-32"> - City 3</option>
<option value="page-section-36"> - City 4</option>
<option value="" disabled>State 2</option>
<option value="page-section-40"> - City 1</option>
</select>
```

Just remove if you want an option disapear

```
$('#options').on('change', function () {
  if(this.value !== "page-section-20"){
      $("#options options[value='page-section-20'").remove();
  }
});
```

This is [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fhzh9xL2/)

Comment: This worked great however I asked the wrong question - See comment below.